# Horizontal menu with vertical submenu

Tags: css, css-float

I was wondering if there was a way to do a Horizontal css menu with horizontal text vertical sub menu with vertical text.. I tried but while rotating the second ul (for vertical) the alignment get collapses. Also I want the menu to flow left until my last vertical menu.. Can this be done? Please help.

```
<style>
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#table-header {
    float: left;
    width: 8%;
}
.vertical-list-container {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
}
.vertical-list{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
.vertical-list-trans{
    float: left;
    border-left:1px solid green;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
</style>

<div class="vertical-list-container">
    <ul class="vertical-list-trans">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>John Doe</li>
        <li>123 Address Lane</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vertical-list-trans">
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Jane Doe</li>
        <li>456 Another Road</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vertical-list-trans">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>John Doe</li>
        <li>123 Address Lane</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Jane Doe</li>
        <li>456 Another Road456 Another Road456 Another Road</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vertical-list-trans">
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Jane Doe</li>
        <li>456 Another Road</li>
        <li>123 Address Lane</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Jane Doe</li>
        <li>456 Another Road456 Another Road456 Another Road</li>
        <li>123 Address Lane</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>Jane Doe</li>
        <li>456 Another Road456 Another Road456 Another Road</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really clear what exactly you want to achieve - could you add an image/mockup?

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you mean, especially by "the alignment get collapses"

Comment: Yeah adding an image of what you're seeing that's not rendering the way you expect, would help clarify this question a great deal

Answer (score 0):

From the [CSS Transforms > Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering) spec on w3.org:

> In the HTML namespace, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element. However, the extent of the overflow area takes into account transformed elements. This behavior is similar to what happens when elements are offset via relative positioning.

See this codepen:
http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/evFof

Notice how the flow of the divs is not changed even though the red one is transformed. The height of that red div is still in the flow of the content and pushes the green div down as if it were not transformed. This is exactly how the transfrom is defined to work in the spec.

This is why, when you rotate your nav items, the alignment appears off. They appear to not wrap close to each other anymore, but really according to the flow, they do.

Here is another example:
http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/DKLHi

Notice in this example how the green div floats next to where the flow of the red div is, and not to the right edge of how it has been transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the problem was in the question, but from the title I think you're looking for a horizontal "menu" with vertical "sub-menus".

You will need to use `transform-origin: top left;` along with `transform: rotate(90deg);` and then fiddle with the positioning `position:absolute; top:--px; left:--px;` on your "sub-menu"

Kind of hard to explain, See jsfiddle for working example.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/SnAF7/2/)